# Kotlin: unchecked type inference based on function return value

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

In Java you can write methods like this one which do not throw any cast warnings and infer the type based on the return type:

```
public static <T> T getService(final String name) {
    return (T) appCtx.getBean(name);
}
```

Here are some usage examples:

```
public static StatusService getStatusService() {
    return getService("statusService");
}

public static VenueService getVenueService() {
    return getService("venueService");
}
```

Now I tried to convert this to Kotlin and came up with this:

```
fun <T> getService(name: String): T {
    return appCtx?.getBean(name) as T
}
```

But here I am getting a cast warning:

```
Unchecked cast: Any? to T
```

Ok, after some browsing on Stackoverflow I found out that you can shut it up with an annotation:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
```

I am not sure this is a clean solution though.

My question is: is there a way to avoid this unchecked type cast warning when you infer the type via the return type in Kotlin? If so how can you do it.

**Update 1**

After some of the answers and comments (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918740/2735286 and Marko Topolnics' comments) I have changed my code to:

```
inline fun <reified T> getService(name: String): T {
    requireNotNull(appCtx) { "Application context has not been set." }
    return appCtx?.getBean(name) as T
}
```

This code eliminates the unchecked cast warning and provides improved error handling.

**Update 2**

After Alexey Romanov's suggestion I have removed `requireNotNull` and changed the code to:

```
var appCtx: ApplicationContext by Delegates.notNull()

private inline fun <reified T> getService(name: String): T {
    return appCtx.getBean(name) as T
}
```

Comment: But the cast to `T` is an unchecked cast. That's a fact. It can even throw an NPE. You could make the type param reified, then the method would make a check before returning the object.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, it can throw an NPE. Yes, using reified might actually help.

Comment: I have noticed that `inline fun <reified T> getService(name: String): T {
        return appCtx?.getBean(name) as T
    }` removes the warning.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You probably know this, but your comment is easy to misunderstand: throwing an exception is not the problem here. What makes the cast unchecked is exactly that it can not throw an exception when it "should".

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes, agree. There's a combination of checked and unchecked because Kotlin will check the part that casts from nullable to non-nullable, but not the part that casts into `T`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik "Kotlin will check the part that casts from nullable to non-nullable" Is there such a part? This seems wrong to me, since `T` can itself be nullable.

Comment: @gil.fernandes I'd suggest using [`Delegates.nonNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/not-null.html) or `lateinit var` instead of `requireNotNull` which will have to be repeated for every method using `appCtx`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Then I was wrong. Yes, the upper bound for `T` is `Any?`. I keep forgetting that. So both the `ClassCastException` and `NullPointerException` would be thrown at the caller side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is why the cast is unchecked and Kotlin's warning is correct:

```
// Java
Object service = <StatusService> getService("venueService");
```

You'll note it compiles *and doesn't throw an exception when executed*. This is because type erasure turns `(T) appCtx.getBean(name)` into `(Object) appCtx.getBean(name)` and this cast obviously always succeeds.

This doesn't happen with `reified T`, because then `T` is known at the call-site, so the cast there is checked.

Comment: Yes, I think that `reified T` seems to be the right way to go. +1

Comment: Yes, it exists exactly to solve this and related problems.

Answer (score 3):

Actually even java compiler (as of JDK 8u131 at least) issues a similar warning. So kotlinc follows the same path.